# Correct Use of Coalesce

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three columns in a table A b and c.  If a is not null then I want to return a  but if it is null I want to return b + c.

I had thought that 
`Select Coalesce(a, b + c) from table1` 
would do the trick but it doesn't seems to which suggests I have the syntax wrong.  Each variant of this I try still seems to return null values for column a when it should be returning a concatenation of b & c because a is null.  I'd welcome your assistance.

I think the syntax is correct, but It's the incorrect use of Coalesce.

Two tables of three columns:

```
Fred Flinstone Tyres    Fred    Flinstone
Norman Greembaum        Norman  Greenbaum
NULL                    Dave    Collins


NULL    2   3
4   5   6
8   6   8
NULL    2   7
```

Sorry the formatting of the second is not as good but it should suffice.  Coalesce seems to work with the lower table when using int datatype but not with the top when usin nvarchar.  Typically of course it's the top table i'm interested in, I would want Dave Collins returned for row 3.

Comment: what rdbms you are using? Mysql? Oracle? DB2? SQL Server?

Comment: rdbms use different syntax of concatenation

Comment: This is using sql Server 2012

Comment: That appears to be correct. If it was a *syntax* error, I'd hope your database would tell you so. If you're getting unexpected results, that *isn't* a syntax error. Just add `,a,b,c` to your select list so that you can inspect the individual values to help diagnose your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Simply ISNULL(a, b+c) will do, in addition its SQL standard too
for concatenation

```
ISNULL(a, CAST(b as varchar) + CAST(c as Varchar))
```

ANd for arithmetic

```
ISNULL(a, ISNULL(b, 0) + ISNULL(c, 0))
```

Comment: if b or c is null then he gets null as well

Comment: +1 `ISNULL()` will probably be the best performer in this case too.

Answer (score 0):

Check 'b' and 'c', I think one of them is null, because if you will sum 1 + null, it will be null

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT COALESCE(a, b + c, b, c) FROM table1
```

or

```
SELECT COALESCE(a, IsNull(b + c,0)) FROM table1
```

Then you get a value for sure that is not null. In your case on of your values probably is null. Check also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

UPDATE:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(a int, b int, c int);
INSERT INTO @table (a,b,c) VALUES (null, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO @table (a,b,c) VALUES (null, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO @table (a,b,c) VALUES (1, 3, 2);
INSERT INTO @table (a,b,c) VALUES (2, 4, 2);

SELECT COALESCE(a,b+c) FROM @table
```

results in:

3
4
1
2

as expected.

Comment: I've been trying this on a very small table, I know that there are nulls in column a, columns b and c both contain values in all rows.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a change that either A or B might be NULL then;

```
ISNULL(a, ISNULL(b + c), 0)
```

Or

```
COALESCE(a, b + c, 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT COALESCE(A,B+C) FROM TABLE1
THERE IS TABLE TABLE1 AND COLUMN A,B,C
IF THE VALUE OF (A=NULL) AND IF THE VALUE OF (B OR C) IS NULL THEN IT WILL RETURN NULL VALUE
table

a       b       c

1   2   3
1   NULL    3
2   NULL    3
2   NULL    4
NULL    2   4
NULL    2   NULL

after, select coalesce (a,b+c) from table1

1
1
2
2
6
NULL

Comment: When you want to post code, or tables where the layout is important, please highlight those blocks and hit the `{}` button. Your tables aren't readable at the moment (there's a preview below the edit box where you can check the layout)